# Installing logstash on apple m1 ARM

Tags: logging, logstash, devops, apple-m1, elk

I'm trying to setup the ELK stack on an apple with the new M1 chip (ARM). When installing logstash, I'm getting the following error:

```
/ % brew install logstash                     
Error: logstash: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
 brew install --build-from-source logstash
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

I also got this message when I tried to install elasticsearch, but I found a solution for that here: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/925#discussioncomment-943622

Is there a similar solution for installing logstash, or something else that works?

Answer (score 2):

Don't recommend you install elastic softwares from `homebrew-core` repo (the default package repo). Homebrew stops distributing newer version of `elasticsearch`, and `kibana`, although you can still get outdated versions in `homebrew-core`.

It's beacause Homebrew defers to the OSI's open source licence definition, and the new license used by elastic softwares is not compatible with it. So, **elastic begins to distribute these software with its own custom tap**.

```sh
# tap maintained by elastic organization
# https://github.com/elastic/homebrew-tap
brew tap elastic/tap

# install logstash
brew install elastic/tap/logstash-full
```

Answer (score 0):

There are currently (as of Aug 2022) issues in building libffi on M1 macs. This is blocking several projects, including logstash which depends on it.

https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/12594

There are several PR's on this topic, but a move from Apple would really help in this.

https://github.com/libffi/libffi/pull/621